# insert or remove enclosing element based on ternary operator JSX

Tags: reactjs, escaping, jsx

I am trying to make the `<pre>` tags appear in the code or not as I need them.

If the text is code I want the `<pre>` tags to exist
If the text is not code then I don't want them to exist

The below code changes depending on the value textIsCode = 1 then the `<pre>` tags are displayed as text. If I remove the quotes around the `<pre>` then the code does not work do I need a different escape character or am I trying to do something the wrong way?

```
const CodeContainerMolecule = (props) => {
  return (
    <section id={props.CodeContainerMolecule_Id} 
    className={props.CodeContainerMolecule_Style}>
      {props.textIsCode === "1" ? '' : `<pre>`}
        <p className="container_component_text">
          {props.text}
        </p>
        {props.textIsCode === "1" ? '' : `</pre>`}
    </section>
  );
};

export default CodeContainerMolecule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the `<pre/>` tags as strings is pretty weird, you'd be better off saving the child in a variable, then just conditionally wrapping it. Something like this:

```
const CodeContainerMolecule = (props) => {
  const child = (
    <p className="container_component_text">
      {props.text}
    </p>
  );

  return (
    <section id={props.CodeContainerMolecule_Id} 
    className={props.CodeContainerMolecule_Style}>
      {props.textIsCode === "1" ? <pre>{child}</pre> : child}
    </section>
  );
};

export default CodeContainerMolecule
```

P.S. there's a difference between a JSX tag, and a string whose context is a JSX tag, they aren't the same

Answer (score 1):

Nesting a `<p>` Paragraph inside a `<pre>`is not an ideal HTML formatting.

```
const CodeContainerMolecule = (props) => {
  return (
    <section id={props.CodeContainerMolecule_Id} 
    className={props.CodeContainerMolecule_Style}>
      {props.textIsCode === "1" ? <p>{props.text}</p> : 
      (<pre> {props.text} </pre>)}
    </section>
  );
};
```

export default CodeContainerMolecule

Comment: This isn't quite right, he still wants the `<p/>` tag stuff there if the text code is "1", he just doens't want the wrapping `<pre/>` tags. In your answer, if the text code is "1" he won't get _anything_

Comment: Thanks! they are both good answers. Thanks also for correcting my spelling!

Comment: @Jayce444 in that case, I agree with you. But my answer is more about the proper way of doing it rather than how he wanted it done. He could use another type of container element like a `div` to wrap as the wrapper instead of `<pre>`.